# ColdFusion - Posting a file to a form with CFHTTP

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to post an XML file to a multipart HTML form, it's not working, and I can't figure out what the problem is. It appears that ColdFusion is just not transmitting the file. I've tried posting to the actual form I need to post to as well as a test page that dumps requests, and all that comes through are the form fields.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
  <cfhttp url="#endPoint#" method="post" multipart="yes">
        <cfhttpparam type="formField" name="file_name" value="test.xml">
        <cfhttpparam type="formField" name="user_name" value="test">
        <cfhttpparam type="formField" name="password" value="test">
        <cfhttpparam type="file" name="test.xml" file="#localfile#">
    </cfhttp>
```

I can confirm that endPoint points to a valid URL, the formField names/values are valid, and that test.xml does indeed exist at the location specified by localfile.

Suggestions? Any input would be appreciated!

Add'l info: I am on CF MX 6.1 if that makes a difference.

**EDIT: After reviewing the input below, I did some more testing.**

I can confirm that localfile is an absolute path (C:\path_to_my_files\test.xml).

I'm not sure what the target form is running on. I don't know for sure, but I don't think it's ColdFusion.

I built my own HTTP test page using GetHTTPRequestData() as mentioned below, and I think that works ok, though it looks a litle strange to me. Writing GetHTTPRequestData().content to a file lets me see what I'm trying to send. However, the final form still reports that I'm not including a file. Posttestserver.com also reports no file. I've included the result from both my page and the POST test server below.

My test page result:

```
-------------------------------7d0d117230764
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_name"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

test.xml
-------------------------------7d0d117230764
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user_name"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

test
-------------------------------7d0d117230764
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

test
-------------------------------7d0d117230764
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test.xml"; filename="C:\my_files\test.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml

%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221%2E0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF%2D8%22%20%3F%3E%3CjobFeed%3E%3Cjob%3E%3CjobId%3E1234%3C%2FjobId%3E%3CjobTitle%3ETest%20Job%3C%2FjobTitle%3E%3CjobCity%3ETest%20City%3C%2FjobCity%3E%3CjobState%3ETest%20State%3C%2FjobState%3E%3CjobDescription%3ETest%20Description%3C%2FjobDescription%3E%3CjobZip%3E12345%3C%2FjobZip%3E%3CjobUrl%3Ehttp%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Etest%2Ecom%3C%2FjobUrl%3E%3CJobType%3ETEC%3C%2FJobType%3E%3C%2Fjob%3E%3C%2FjobFeed%3E


-------------------------------7d0d117230764--
```

I've got no idea what this "-------------------------------7d0d117230764" business is.

Here's what I got from the test site:

```
Headers (Some may be inserted by server)
UNIQUE_ID = TlZTra3sqvkAAECsSBsAAAAL
HTTP_HOST = www.posttestserver.com
HTTP_CONNECTION = close
HTTP_USER_AGENT = ColdFusion
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = deflate, gzip, x-gzip, compress, x-compress
CONTENT_TYPE = multipart/form-data; boundary=-----------------------------7d0d117230764
CONTENT_LENGTH = 1159
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = CGI/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD = POST
QUERY_STRING = 
REQUEST_URI = /post.php
REQUEST_TIME = 1314280365

Post Params:
key: 'file_name' value: 'test.xml'
key: 'user_name' value: 'test'
key: 'password' value: 'test'

== Begin post body ==

== End post body ==
```

Here it appears I've transmitted no file.

I'm still looking at it, but I'm not seeing the problem. Ideas?

Comment: Works fine for me under 6.1. Is it possible something else is interfering. What does `getHttpRequestData()` report?

Comment: Is there content between your begin and end post body? The `---------` bits are multipart boundaries, where the server knows that a new type of data is coming through. That way it knows where one bit of data (a form field) stops, and the next bit of data (the file you're sending) begins. What you're seeing is correct, you just have to understand that a binary file *is not* actually included in a form field. The *name* of a file can be sent in a corresponding form field, but the file itself is sent as part of the post body.

Comment: Right, I understand what you're saying about the file and the post body. I am just missing an important point that you and Leigh are making? Based on the docs I have and some Googling, what I'm doing with the <cfhttpparam type="file" ...> tag should work just fine. I mean, my CF page receives the message body, I don't see why the external ones don't.

Comment: I do not think you are misunderstanding. From what I can see we have confirmed two ways that CF is sending a file. Are you sure Posttestserver.com is working the way you expect? I just tried the same thing with a regular `<form>` and it reported: *3 post variables. Post body was 0 chars long.*

Comment: Maybe a silly question but does posttestserver.com handle multipart file uploads? From what I can tell it seems to only process simple form parameters (not files). It does recognize files submitted as the *body* of the request, which is a little different ie <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#xmlToSend#">. But it does not seem to acknowledge/handle multipart file uploads.

Comment: Not a silly question - I had just assumed that it did. I emailed the guy who built it to ask, and he said 'probably not'. I'm really not sure what else to do besides keep waiting for a response from the folks behind my target form. I will add any useful new information I come across here for posterity.

Thanks for all the input

Comment: @catbot - Could it be the target is just expecting you to submit the file differently (ie *not* as a multipart file upload)? What do their specs say exactly? Because I think we have confirmed the file *is* being sent, suggesting the real issue may be *how* it is being sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the endPoint is a CF page, then I am wondering if something else may be going on. The data is sent in the request body, yes. But with CF pages, it should still parse the information and create a form field for that file. Same as with a regular form upload. In this case the field name would be `form["test.xml"]`. Could that be part of the issue?

**CFDUMP results under MX6.1 and CF9**

```
FIELDNAMES FILE_NAME,USER_NAME,PASSWORD,TEXT.XML 
FILE_NAME test.xml 
PASSWORD test 
TEXT.XML C:\CFusionMX\...\temp\wwwroot-tmp\neotmp6275345679234991.tmp 
USER_NAME test
```

Note: One difference under CF9 was that `getHttpRequestData().content` is empty. Whereas under MX6 it is still populated. Seems like 6.1 preserves a copy of the data (after processing it) but CF9 does not. Not sure why.

Comment: Are you saying that I should try specifying my file as a form field? I tried that and it didn't work, same results as above.

Comment: (Edit) No. I was saying the original code worked fine for me and was suggesting you test it against a CF page first to confirm there were no obvious problems. (A <cfdump var="#FORM#"> should have shown the same information I posted above.). But based on your updates, it would seem you have already confirmed the request is including the file.

Answer (score 3):

When you specify a type of file, then the file data is sent in the post body, not in a form field name that you can reference. If you check the [LiveDocs on CFHTTPPARAM](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d85.html) it states for  the `type="file"` attribute:

> The absolute path to the file that is sent in the request body.

So as Leigh stated, on your receiving page, you need to use `GetHttpRequestData`, something like this:

```
<cfset objRequest = GetHttpRequestData() />
<cfset object = objRequest.Content() />
```